# Elasticsearch: is caching Java client okay?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch. I am testing it out. I have the following Java method to get client (Config is a Java object holding constants):

```
public Client getClient() {
    Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
            .put("cluster.name", Config.ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTER).build();
    Client client = new TransportClient(settings)
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(
                    Config.ELASTICSEARCH_SERVER, Config.ELASTICSEARCH_SERVER_PORT));
    return client;
}
```

Once the client is obtained, it is used as follows (search, also used in index, updating):

```
Client client = getClient();                                             
SearchResponse scrollResp = client.prepareSearch(Config.ELASTICSEARCH_DOC
        .setTypes(Config.ELASTICSEARCH_DOC_TYPE)                         
        .setQuery(query)                                                 
        .setFrom(0)                                                      
        .setSize(Config.ELASTICSEARCH_PAGE_SIZE).execute().actionGet();
```

I notice that getClient() takes quite some time in each call. I would like to catch the obtained client in the caller and reuse it each time when the next page of documents is retrieved. Does this make sense? Any side effect?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes -- you want to re-use your `client` for multiple operations... the documentation ecourages this behavior -- http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html#transport-client -- has an example that shows `//on startup`, and `// on shutdown`

I believe that TransportClient is thread-safe (can't find any reference to that, but I use it in multi-threaded code currently without protecting it).

Comment: Alcanzar, I wanted to reuse it not only in multiple operations, but also in multiple web sessions. So, I can reuse the client by saving it. Correctly? Thanks so much for your help!